# unknown parameter: -conf Error in osm2pgrouting

Tags: pgrouting, ubuntu, osm2pgrouting

I was just going through the following tutorial **[HERE](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/osm2pgrouting.html#run-osm2pgrouting)**.

I have extracted all the files succesfully using the below commands:

```
cd ~/Desktop/pgrouting-workshop/
tar -xvzf data.tar.
```

But when i run the following command:

```
osm2pgrouting -file "data/sampledata.osm" \
                          -conf "/usr/share/osm2pgrouting/mapconfig.xml" \
                          -dbname pgrouting-workshop \
                          -user user \
  -host localhost \
                          -clean
```

I get an error as follows:

```
unknown parameter:  -conf
```

What am i doing wrong ??

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the master or develop branch of osm2pgrouting, I notice the help is a little different between the two.

I'm using the develop branch and it has these instructions:

```
-c [ --conf ] arg (=/usr/share/osm2pgrouting/mapconfig.xml)
```

Full instructions:

```
Allowed options:

Help:
  --help                Produce help message for this version.

General:
  -f [ --file ] arg                     Name of your osm file (Required).
  -c [ --conf ] arg (=/usr/share/osm2pgrouting/mapconfig.xml)
                                        Name of your configuration xml file.
  --prefix arg (=planet_)               Prefix added at the beginning of table 
                                        names.
  --suffix arg                          Suffix added at the end of table names.
  -s [ --skipnodes ] arg (=1)           When ture: dont import the node table.
  --clean arg (=0)                      When true: Drop previously created 
                                        tables.

Database options:
  -d [ --dbname ] arg            Name of your database (Required).
  -u [ --user ] arg (=mapas)     Name of the user, which have write access to 
                                 the database.
  -h [ --host ] arg (=localhost) Host of your postgresql database.
  -p [ --db_port ] arg (=5432)   db_port of your database.
  --passwd arg                   Password for database access.
```

So you would need to do this:

-c "path/here"

or what I do

--conf="path/here"

Comment: Confirmed with pgRouting folks -- the tutorials is based on osm2pgrouting older version, but looks like you are using the newer version. So follow the new instructions.